# Is it possible to use jszip library in react native?

Tags: react-native, jszip

I want to zip my video to reduce its file size. Is it possible to use jszip library  (https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) to do this? or is there any alternative library?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jszip) library for `react-native`